# What's the difference between "perpendicular" and "vertical"?

Tags: word-usage

What's the difference between **"perpendicular"** and **"vertical"**?
In geometry, why say "make a perpendicular line to CD through point D" instead of "make a vertical line of CD through point D"?
Or they have the same meaning and usage?
Which of the two I should use in what certain cases?

Comment: Did you look up the definition of the two words?  *Perpendicular* means "at right angles to something"; *vertical* means "straight up and down".

Comment: I have a hard time believing that in Chinese there is no difference in geometry between a perpendicular and a vertical line. Vertical is up and down. Perpendicular means at a right angle.

Comment: They have the same result in Google Translate and their Chinese explanations are so similar, even wrong in some places. This led to my question.

Comment: Yiongie, don't you have a good Chinese<>English dictionary? Google Translate is a mess. You can't expect it to be right all the time. If you plan to do a lot of English, I suggest you get a good English<>English dictionary and a good bilingual one. Hard-copy dictionaries (of good ones online) are better than all these automatic translation sites.

Comment: I think there is the same issue in as in Japanese.  While you can be explicit, the idiom is say, (literally) "the wall is perpendicular" (or even more literally "hanging truly") instead of "vertical"  You can say "perpendicular to the horizontal" but that is normally omitted, or rather is implied by context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As adjectives the difference between perpendicular and vertical, is that perpendicular is (geometry) at or forming a right angle (to) while vertical is along the direction of a plumbline or along a straight line that includes the center of the earth e.g.

> make a perpendicular line to CD through point D

The above is very clear that the line has to perpendicular 90 degrees to the line CD *and* pass through point D

> make a vertical line to CD through point D

This is quite specific, maybe a little *too specific*, as it means the line *has* to be pointing upwards and downwards, while perpendicular means it just has to be 90 degrees to a line, in any direction wherever the line is.

[perpendicular vs vertical](https://wikidiff.com/perpendicular/vertical#:%7E:text=As%20adjectives%20the%20difference%20between,the%20center%20of%20the%20earth.)

Vertical means perpendicular to the horizontal - @PrimeMover

Comment: Might be worth pointing out that "vertical means perpendicular to the horizontal" which puts them in context with each other.